# How to select audio / subtitle in a custom cast app on a mpd file containing already all tracks?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, audiotrack, google-cast-sdk

I'm creating a sender/receiver Chromecast App on Android device to display movies.

I'm using a .mpd file containing already the video, the audio tracks, and subtitles.
So my question is how to add a selection button for those tracks?

I only found how to add tracks with different files (.vtt, .mp3, ..) but not with them inside the video file.
Doc I'm using: [URL](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/advanced)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: well, thanks for the spacing correction and the downvote but do you have any clue to my problem ?..

Comment: Can you please post the answer of how you solved it? It will really help us

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the android sender [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/media_tracks). The 'Remove Tracks' sections talks about how to enable/disable tracks using [setActiveMediaTracks](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient.html#setActiveMediaTracks(long%5B%5D)).

If the media contains the tracks once it has finished loading you should be able to enable/disable the tracks.

Comment: thanks for you answer; I finally found how to play the track I wanted, but still nothing to know which tracks are available on the file I'm playing.

Comment: @nobody710 look at [MediaInfo](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaInfo) getMediaTracks should return the available tracks.

Comment: @nobody710 can you help me out with this stuck with same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343201/changing-audio-track-in-remote-media-client-in-cast